# Update user meta on custom wordpress form and redirect

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a fully functioning custom wordpress form that updates the user meta when they are logged in, however when I submit it just reloads the same page I am on, I am trying to get it to redirect to a thank you page.  How would I go about this?  Current working code I am using below.  Thanks.

```
    <?php  
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
    if($_POST['gender'] != '') {
    $gender_update = $_POST['gender'];
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID,'gender', $gender_update);
    }
        ?>

<?php
function curURL() {
$pageURL = 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
return $pageURL;
}
?>

<form name="userform" method="post" id="adduser" class="user-forms" action="<?php echo curURL(); ?>"  >
```

Answer (score 0):

`update_user_meta` returns false on failure, or if no change was made:

```
$result = update_user_meta( $current_user->ID,'gender', $gender_update );
if( false !== $result ) {
    wp_safe_redirect( home_url( '/thanks/' ) );
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Does this code mean it will redirect if no change was made?  The form is blank to begin with so there will always be data to add to the user meta, so Im not sure this code will work?

Comment: It'll redirect if a value is added or changed

Comment: ok great thank you, adding this to my code redirects the page when i load it, not on form submit....any ideas?

Comment: You should probably check if the var is set: `if(isset($_POST['gender'])){ //do update and redirect stuff }`